# tmux highlight mode with search

Tags: search, vim, copy, highlight, tmux

In tmux I'm using vim mode to copy from the terminal buffer. The only thing I cannot accomplish that I usually do on vim is to go into highlight mode and highlight everything from current cursor posistion until the next occurence of a pattern search. For example, in vim if I go into visual mode (v) and then type (/*pathern*) all the text between the cursor position until the next occurence of *pathern* is highlighted.

Does anyone has a clue on how to accomplish such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

so far tmux doesn't ship this feature. In copy mode you can use vim/emacs keybindings, but it is not a vim/emacs after all.

`v` then `f/F` works though. You can try submitting a feature request.

Or you can cp the buffer into your vim, and do whatever there.